# Token in query string with Django REST Framework's TokenAuthentication

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

In an API built with [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) authentication can be done using the TokenAuthentication method. Its [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) says the authentication token should be sent via an `Authorization` header.

Often one can send API-keys or tokens via a query string in order to authenticate, like `https://domain.com/v1/resource?api-key=lala`.

Is there a way to do the same with Django REST Framework's TokenAuthentication?

Answer (score 20):

By default DRF doesn't support query string to authenticate, but you can easily override their `authenticate` method in `TokenAuthentication` class to support it.

An example would be:

```
class TokenAuthSupportQueryString(TokenAuthentication):
    """
    Extend the TokenAuthentication class to support querystring authentication
    in the form of "http://www.example.com/?auth_token=<token_key>"
    """
    def authenticate(self, request):
        # Check if 'token_auth' is in the request query params.
        # Give precedence to 'Authorization' header.
        if 'auth_token' in request.query_params and \
                        'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' not in request.META:
            return self.authenticate_credentials(request.query_params.get('auth_token'))
        else:
            return super(TokenAuthSupportQueryString, self).authenticate(request)
```

Comment: Just in case, `TokenAuthentication` class is imported with `from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication`. Also don't forget to either add this as `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` in settings, or define it per-view using `authentication_classes = (TokenAuthSupportQueryString,)`

Answer (score 6):

```
class QueryStringBasedTokenAuthentication(TokenAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        key = request.query_params.get('auth_token').strip()
        if key:
            return self.authenticate_credentials(key)
        return False
```

`DRF` has `TokenAuthentication` which looks for `token` in `header`. The method `authenticate_credentials` takes care verifying the token.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2018 using Django Rest Framework you can create your own Authentication class see http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#extending-jsonwebtokenauthentication

```
class JSONWebTokenAuthenticationQS(BaseJSONWebTokenAuthentication):
    def get_jwt_value(self, request):
        return request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('jwt')
```

Then in the APIView class add
`authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthenticationQS,)`

Or 
`@authentication_classes((JSONWebTokenAuthenticationQS,))`

On the view function.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Scott Warren's answer. That was a step in the right direction, because the DRFJWT docs don't include the important authentication_classes line. But with that, as noted in [Issue 441](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/issues/441) there is a big problem that you can't mix the JWT authentication methods. I ended up with:

```
class JSONWebTokenAuthenticationQS(JSONWebTokenAuthentication):
    def get_jwt_value(self, request):
        return request.GET.get('jwt') or JSONWebTokenAuthentication.get_jwt_value(self, request)
```

which so far seems to work well. It uses JSONWebTokenAuthentication instead of the Base class, because it has to in order to use the original get_jwt_value method.

Answer (score -1):

refer answer of `OmriToptix` and `Scott Warren` and others website [1](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/authentication.py) and [2](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#extending-jsonwebtokenauthentication)

for now most case use `JSONWebTokenAuthentication`, so now should override its `get_jwt_value`, full code is:

```
# from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import BaseJSONWebTokenAuthentication
from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.authentication import get_authorization_header

class JWTAuthByQueryStringOrHeader(JSONWebTokenAuthentication):
# class JWTAuthByQueryStringOrHeader(BaseJSONWebTokenAuthentication):
    """
    Extend the TokenAuthentication class to support querystring authentication
    in the form of "http://www.example.com/?jwt_token=<token_key>"
    """

    def get_jwt_value(self, request):
        # Check if 'jwt_token' is in the request query params.
        # Give precedence to 'Authorization' header.
        queryParams = request.query_params
        reqMeta = request.META

        if ('jwt_token' in queryParams) and ('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' not in reqMeta):
            jwt_token = queryParams.get('jwt_token')
            # got jwt token from query parameter
            return jwt_token
        else:
            # call JSONWebTokenAuthentication's get_jwt_value
            # to get jwt token from header of 'Authorization'
            return super(JWTAuthByQueryStringOrHeader, self).get_jwt_value(request)
```

here save above code to `apps/util/jwt_token.py`, then **NOT FORGET** add related `Django` settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        # 'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'apps.util.jwt_token.JWTAuthByQueryStringOrHeader',
        ...
    ),
    ...
}
```

now frontend/web side can call api like this:

`http://localhost:65000/api/v1/scripts/3d9e77b0-e538-49b8-8790-60301ca79e1d/script_word_export/?jwt_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMWVkMGEwZDgtMmFiYi00MDFkLTk5NTYtMTQ5MzcxNDIwMGUzIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJsc2R2aW5jZW50IiwiZXhwIjoxNTMxOTAyOTU0LCJlbWFpbCI6InZpbmNlbnQuY2hlbkBuYXR1cmxpbmcuY29tIn0.wheM7Fmv8y8ysz0pp-yUHFqfk-IQ5a8n_8OplbYkj7s`

to pass `jwt_token` into server side, get authorized to download/export the file.

while still support original method `pass jwt token inside header 'Authorization'`:

```
POST http://localhost:65000/api/v1/scripts/3d9e77b0-e538-49b8-8790-60301ca79e1d/script_word_export/
Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMWVkMGEwZDgtMmFiYi00MDFkLTk5NTYtMTQ5MzcxNDIwMGUzIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJsc2R2aW5jZW50IiwiZXhwIjoxNTMxOTAyOTU0LCJlbWFpbCI6InZpbmNlbnQuY2hlbkBuYXR1cmxpbmcuY29tIn0.wheM7Fmv8y8ysz0pp-yUHFqfk-IQ5a8n_8OplbYkj7s
```